# reload script on browser resize

Tags: jquery, responsive-design, navigation

I'm working on a horizontal Navigation Bar for a Responsive Website. 
I create a jQuery-script to calculates how many list elements can be displayed before they are wrapped.

so far so good...

now to my question: 
How can I use `$(window).resize` to recalculate the number list-elements before they are wrapped?

JS:

```
$(function () {

    var totalWidth = 0;
    var menu = $('nav ul');
    var menuWidth = menu.innerWidth();

    menu.find('li').each(function () {
        totalWidth += $(this).outerWidth();
        if (totalWidth > menuWidth) {
            console.log(totalWidth);
            $(this).before('<li class="more-content"><a>More</a><ul>'); 
            $('.nav .menu li:last').after('</li>');
            $(".more-content").nextAll().appendTo(".more-content ul");
            return false; // Abort loop
        }
    });

})
```

here is the jsfiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/daveleeone/vB34p/

Thanks Davelee

Comment: Welcome to SO! And always put your code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Create your initialization function where you put code that idcalled ony once.

```
var menu = $('nav ul');
```

Than onUpdate function what recalculate new values.

```
var totalWidth = 0;
var menuWidth = menu.innerWidth();
menu.find('li').each(function () {
    totalWidth += $(this).outerWidth();
    if (totalWidth > menuWidth) {
        console.log(totalWidth);
        $(this).before('<li class="more-content"><a>More</a><ul>'); 
        $('.nav .menu li:last').after('</li>');
        $(".more-content").nextAll().appendTo(".more-content ul");
        return false; // Abort loop
    }
});
```

Call `initializaton` and even there the `onUpdate` once. Than just call `onUpadte` even is the window resized.

Comment: Thanks for reply! What do you mean with onUpdate-function? Now I modified my code as follows: 
http://jsfiddle.net/daveleeone/u7u6t/3/